# How to do regularization in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, optimal-control, quadratic-programming, linear-control

For quadratic programming, the trick can be implementing an constant. Example:

$$H = A^T Q A$$

$$Min: \frac{1}{2}x^THx + c^T x$$

Where $Q = \alpha I$

This gives more smooth optimal values. Just set $\alpha$ to a value like 0.85 and everything will be fine.

But how would I do that for linear programming?

$$Max: c^Tx$$
S.t
$$Ax \le b \\ x \ge 0$$

I know that for ordinary least squares:

$$x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$

Then we can add this feature and it will give us a regularized solution.

$$x = (A^TA + \alpha I)^{-1}A^Tb$$

But how should I write my objective function so it has the feature as well?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Also please note that your "quadratic" is in fact just a linear least squares norm minimization.

Comment: @mathreadler Not sure what you mean by that. But I like the url link you gave me. If I want to implement that on linear programming. How should I shape $c$ vector then? If I say that $c = A^T b$ and $Ax = b$ ?

Comment: expand $\frac 1 2 \| Q^{1/2}Ax \|_2^2$ and you will see it becomes precisely first term.

Comment: Give that to $c$?

Comment: "implementing an constant"... wut?

Comment: @mathreadler Practical control theory stuffs. :)

Comment: I have had a couple of courses in control theory too.

Comment: @mathreadler Great! Well in Model Predictive Control, you can add that constant and it will prevent dead-beat control.

Comment: Maybe then you should actually add it instead of multiply with it?

Comment: @mathreadler If I want to "solve" $Ax=b$ with constraints, then I set $c = A^T*b$, but that will give me some problems.

Comment: You can rewrite it as $\min_x \|Ax-b\|_2^2$ and then incorporate constraints as other cost terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer!

Let's say that you have the system $Ax = b$. OK! Then you want to find $x$ with regularization.

Use ordinary least square:

$$x = (A^TA + \alpha I)^{-1}A^Tb$$

If you want the same result, but using linear programming.

$$max : c^T x$$
With S.t to:
$$Ax \le b \\ x \ge 0$$

Then you need to replace the constraints and the objective function to:

$$max : (A^TA + \alpha I)^Tb x$$
With S.t to:
$$(A^TA + \alpha I)x \le A^Tb \\ x \ge 0$$

GNU Octave example:

```
>> A = [3 1; 4 6];
>> b = [3; 6];
>> a = 0.01; % Alpha is small
>> x = inv(A'*A + a*eye(2))*A'*b % Ordinary least square
x =

   0.85612
   0.42920

>> x = glpk((A'*A + a*eye(2))'*b, A'*A + a*eye(2), A'*b, [], [], repmat("U", 1, 2), repmat("C", 1, 2), -1) % LP
x =

   0.85612
   0.42920

>>
```

Comment: so the regularized problem does not depend on $c$?

Comment: @LinAlg Well, I tried to use different values on $c$ but it did not result the same as ordinary least squares. So I think that $c$ should have that shape/value. Looks good for me.

Answer (score 1):

A typical linear least squares problem can be

$${\bf x_o} = \min_{\bf x}\left\{\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2\right\}$$
with added Tikhonov regularization:

$${\bf x_o} = \min_{\bf x}\left\{\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2 + \lambda \|{\bf I x}\|_2^2\right\}$$

which after expansion and differentiation setting $= 0$ vector et.c. reduces to

$${\bf x_o} = ({\bf A}^T{\bf A}+\lambda {\bf I})^{-1}({\bf A}^T{\bf b})$$

so the regularization is added to the ${\bf A}^T{\bf A}$ matrix in the left hand side, not multiplied somewhere in the middle of it.

so this $\bf A$ we have is in fact ${\bf Q}^{1/2}{\bf A}$ above so it will expand to:

$${\bf x_o} = ({\bf A}^T{\bf Q}^{T/2}{\bf Q}^{1/2}{\bf A}+\lambda {\bf I})^{-1}({\bf A}^T{\bf b})$$

Now assuming ${\bf Q}^{T/2}{\bf Q}^{1/2} = {\bf Q}$, well otherwise ${\bf Q}^{1/2}$ above would not even be defined.

$${\bf x_o} = ({\bf A}^T{\bf QA}+\lambda {\bf I})^{-1}({\bf A}^T{\bf b})$$

Comment: How can I implement that on the objective function?

Comment: But that's ordinary least square?

Comment: I need to use the simplex method for maximization.

Comment: Your question says nothing about any extra condition.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You can't do that after you have gotten an answer..

Comment: I just make it much clear. Felt that my question was not clear enough.

Comment: What is matrix $Q$  ?

Comment: I posted an answer too. Please have a look at it.